# Process Template Update Error on Migrating to TFS 2013

Tags: tfs, tfs-process-template

I am trying to upgrade from TFS 2010 to TFS 2013.
The Update went well and the only problem I have now is when I try to Configure the web access features it gives me the following error.

```
[Warning] TF400609: Cannot add the action 'Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.StartWork' to the work      item type 'Task' because the state 'New' does not exist.

[Warning] TF400609: Cannot add the action 'Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.StopWork' to the work item type 'Task' because the state 'New' does not exist.

[Error] TF400654: Unable to configure Planning Tools. The following element contains an error: BugWorkItems/BugWorkItems. TF400506: This element defines the states for work items that represent Bugs or Defects. Each state must exist in at least one of the work item types that are defined in: BugWorkItems. The following states do not exist in any of the work item types: Active.

[Error] TF400654: Unable to configure Planning Tools. The following element contains an error: BugWorkItems/BugWorkItems. TF400507: Each work item type must support an initial state value that matches one of the states defined in: BugWorkItems. The following work item types have initial states that do not include any states defined in the bug state configuration: Bug.
```

Since my previous process template was customized I know I need to do the same here and update the new process template. Since I do not have Visual Studio Professional Licence I do not have process template editor. So I went on and Changes the templates manually.

Basically in the Task items I renamed the status 'Active' to 'New' and in the Bug Item I renamed the 'Active' to 'Initiated' which was used in my project.

And I uploaded this edited template back and tried to configure the web access pages having no luck.

Any clue on where I went wrong? The error message does not change whatever the changes I make to the process template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to [export process configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500413.aspx) using `witadmin exportprocessconfig`.

Change the `States` elements to match your work items states.

Then [export categories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd273721.aspx) and all categories matches your workflow requirements.